# Sticky Sessions with Message Broker

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, messagebroker

I'm working on a project where we are trying to utilize message brokering where after a type message starts going to a given consumer, it continues to go to that consumer. This is essentially the same as direct exchange in rabbitmq - except the keys are dynamic. Here's a more detailed description of what I'm looking for:

Imagine a situation with multiple producers and multiple consumers. The producers are sending multiple messages which should be broken down by some type of integer. Any message with any given integer will always go to the same consumer. All messages of type 5 will go to the consumer handling message 5. However, the integer could be any number. It is not predefined how many message types there will be.

So, this design needs to support X producers, Y consumers, and Z message types, and any given message type must always route to the same consumer.

I'm a bit new to message brokers, so excuse me if I'm using the wrong terminology or asking about something simple. I wasn't able to find the answer through searching around.

Answer (score -1):

please check out the RabbitMQ tutorials that concern [topic exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html). I believe that using a topic exchange will meet your requirements.